# HTML.DropDownList and CSS

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML markup in a form(this is a partial view).  It functions well, except that the href does not receive the CSS styling it should.  It still works as a link, but it does not receive the proper style.  This site is a standard Microsoft MVC 5 site.  If I move the href above the dropdownlist, it styles correctly.  Any ideas?

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="text-align:right">Select Ad Type:</div><div class="col-md-8">@Html.DropDownList("AdList", null, new { @id = "adtype" })</div>
<div class="col-md-12"><a href="#">Link Tag</a></div>
```

Comment: Hi @macgeezer - you'll need to provide more context about the issue, like a better example or the related CSS. I don't think your problem can be reproduced without more information. See this example I made: https://jsfiddle.net/p3ng4rv7/

Comment: Also, if those two divs are toghether inside the same `<div class="row"></div>`, change one class so that combined result in 12 columns, for example: `<div class="col-md-4">...` and the other `<div class="col-md-8">...` For details check [bootstrap docs here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Comment: zed,  thanks.  I had misplaced some of the <div class="row"></div> tags and your comment made me tidy that up.  It did not solve the issue however.  I just added a specific style to the <a> tag and now I have what i needed.  That was quicker than trying to run down why it didn't style properly